How to estimate the tree coverage by using LiDAR
I have LiDAR data, provided as a LAS file.
How would I measure the ground covered by trees?
For example, with this dataset: neonscience.org

Wouldn't this be rather a question for GIS SE, at least if you're also interested in a specific implementation?

Oh I'm pretty new to this topic, so I didn't know GIS SE existed. So I guess you are right :)
